# Single email account accessed by multiple users

Tags: email

We would like to setup a support email account for a company with the following features:

1. There is a single email account for support, for example, support@company.com
2. This account should be accessed by more than one support people
3. All people accessing this account should be able to reply to incoming emails and include their own signature at the end but emails should always be sent from support@company.com

Here is an example scenario:

- The support@company.com inbox has 10 emails.
- Support people John and Michael can both check the emails and reply to any one of them. If one person is reading or replying to an email, all others can see that, so they do not reply to the same email.
- If John replies to an email, his signature is used in the reply and the same goes for Michael or any other support person.
- All emails are sent through support@company.com (there is always a single company support email)

Can someone suggest a tool that can do this? Can G-suite by Google handle this?

At the moment we do this using a regular Gmail account (by granting access to additional users) but the problem is that the email signature cannot change (to reflect the person who handles the reply) and in the email sent, there is always an additional information to the 'From' information mentioning the actual email of the person who sent the email

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a power user question...

But Office365 is great for this and then create a shared mailbox or a team email.

[office 365 team email](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-a-site-mailbox-to-collaborate-and-coordinate-team-email-57e361eb-39ef-400e-92de-f6408dab6b2b)